# Angular : Put in ng-model a value set in scope

Tags: angularjs

In the ng-model, i want to set a default value defined in my scope but the value is not recognized.

Here's my controller :

```
$scope.defaultRole = "Admin";
```

My view :

```
<input type="text" 
class="form-control" ng-model="user.role='{{defaultRole}}'">
```

but i have **{{defaultRole}}** instead of **Admin** in my input text. Maybe it's a problem of formating but i dont know how to make it work.

Note : i can put ng-model="user.role='Admin'" directly, but i want it from the scope.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You don't understand how ngModel works. ngModel expects an assignable angular expression. The expression is bound two way. That means that

- to populate the input field, angular evaluates the expression
- when the value entered in the input field changes, the variable that the ngModel expression refers to is set to the entered value

So, all you need is

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="defaultRole">
```

That will read the defaultRole variable and populate the field with its value, and vice versa.

If you want, instead, to populate `user.role` with the entered value, and the field to have the defaultRole value by default, then it should be

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.role">
```

and the controller should do

```
$scope.user.role = $scope.defaultRole;
```

or, if user doesn't exist yet

```
$scope.user = {
    role: $scope.defaultRole
};
```

to initialize `user.role` to its default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `ng-init`. `ng-model` isn't suppose to deal with affectation. This will be done directly by angular.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.role" ng-init="user.role = defaultRole">
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tmf0n73c/)

Comment: This [is not an appropriate usage of ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).  "The only appropriate use of `ngInit` is for aliasing special properties of `ngRepeat`".  While this *might* work, `ngInit` is a directive, with a priority, which means it is not guaranteed to execute in the order you may expect.  It is possible that the value may be `undefined` because `ngInit` did not process yet.  The **only** appropriate way to initialize variables is with a controller.

Comment: Hi Pierre-Alexandre. Thanks for you short and easy answer that works. I just had to remove the {{}} then. I realized that the ngModel deal with affectation too, but i will follow your advice and use the ng-init instead.

Comment: Now i want to retrieve the values selected in my 2 dropdownlist, concatenate them with a seperator  '-' and then set them to the ng-init. I'm able to retrieve the values selected, but how can i concatenate them ? I tried something like this : ng-init= "user.role = defaultRole - name_selected - adress_selected  "  but it's not working. Do you have an idea how ? thank you